# Is there a way I can have my website send an email without executing a script

Tags: javascript, ajax, email

I want to add a contact page on my webpage. However, I'm apparently not allowed to execute a script on my site since it's hosted on a protected school server.

Is there a work-around where I could send an email on the client side? (maybe some ajax trick?)

All I've found so far is a way to use javascript to open the default mail client and prefill all the data. However, I don't really like that. I'd really like a way to send an email directly from my site. I was even thinking that I could create a java applet to create my email page if that's possible.

Comment: There are services available that will let you do this, use Google.

Comment: @adeneo are you saying that there is a Google API that I could use?

Comment: I think he meant Google for the services available. I added one to my answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃 do you happen to know if there is any downside to using a service like the one you posted?

Comment: No immediate major downsides come to mind. You obviously have no control over the technical process, the features etc. (advanced features come with a price tag at the service I linked to) but if it works, it's pretty neat -  the user doesn't even see the remote service as you (presumably) can make the service redirect to a "thank you" page of your own once the E-Mail was sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to send an E-Mail from the client without the user's consent.

It would be a horrendous security problem if it were possible.

You could make use of a remote form mailing service like [FormToEmail](http://formtoemail.com/), though.